# "watch" and tell how long it has been watching

Tags: linux, watch

I need to repeatedly execute a command (e.g. ls) on a linux OS and I also would like to know **how long it has been running** since I started watching it.

I know I can use `watch` to execute the command. My question is how I can show when the "watch" was started? Or how long it has been watching?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not supported out of the box, but you can hack around it by supplying a more complex command.

```
watch bash -c '"echo $(($(date +%s) - '$(date +%s)'))s; echo ---; ls"'
```

Instead of directly watching the command you want (`ls` in this toy example), watch a `bash` instance, because it can parse a command line and do more. We tell this `bash` to execute three commands, the first of which calculates the difference between the seconds since epoch at `watch` invocation and the seconds since epoch at `bash` invocation. The second prints a line because for prettiness, and the third then executes the desired command.

Showing when the watch started follows the same idea, but is simpler:

```
watch bash -c "'echo $(date); echo ---; ls'"
```

Note that the order of the quotes is not random. The last command could have also been written similar to the above one:

```
watch bash -c '"echo '$(date)'; echo ---; ls"'
```